# show pop up like gmail in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

**I want to show an alert in my android just like gmail notification in desktop**

[image]

how should I approach.

**Solution made it showing like this**

[image]

Comment: I find this question **very** constructive as I was looking for a solution as well. I actually find that it happens **far too often** that questions are closed as **not constructive** by biased people.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dialogs cannot be triggered without an activity..

So ,you can create an activity with dialog theme.

```
    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Now from your service ..just call this activity when your notification arrives... And it will pop up like a dialog...

Edit:

While calling your activity:

```
   startActivity(intent);
   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.right_exit_anim);
```

Now create the two anim files in a seperate folder called anim in the resource dir.

enter_anim:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
   <translate
    android:fromYDelta="20%p" //this takes val from 0(screenbottom) to 100(screentop).
    android:toYDelta="0%p"  //this takes val from 0(screenbottom) to 100(screentop).
    android:duration="700"   //transition timing
    />
   </set>
```

exit_anim:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
   <translate
    android:fromYDelta="0%p" //this takes val from 0(screenbottom) to 100(screentop).
    android:toYDelta="20%p"  //this takes val from 0(screenbottom) to 100(screentop).
    android:duration="700"   //transition timing
    />
   </set>
```

EDIT 2:

Create an activity.. design it..then go to your manifest file.. And under your activity tag.. add:

```
    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Now your activity will look like a dialog...

EDIT 3:

Now add the following function in your activity(dialog) after onCreate():

```
    @Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.BOTTOM;//setting the gravity just like any view
    lp.x = 10;
    lp.y = 10;
    lp.width = 200;
    lp.height = 100;
    getWindowManager().updateViewLayout(view, lp);
}
```

We are overriding the attach window to specify the activity location on the screen.

Now your activity will be placed in the right side bottom of the screen.

EDIT 4:

Now to give your specified co ordinate points for the dialog, use the lp.x and lp.y...

Comment: But can I show that acivity looks like dialog from downside of my android screen

Comment: make a small dialog... and then apply enter and exit animation to it...

Comment: Can u please provide any example

Comment: @bumba, have a look at the edited answer..i hope it helps.

Comment: I am assuming that u already created a dialog activity. NO I have not

Comment: @bumba, i have edited again... :)

Comment: transition timing it is mili sec

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31165/discussion-between-amal-and-bumba)

Comment: it's working but not showing from right side

Comment: @bumba.. check the 3rd Edit... it should work fine..

Comment: Yes it worked but why it showing only "New" where is the activity content

Comment: change the lp.width and lp.height accordingly...It will show the content @bumba

Comment: one more help how to put it more right and more down

Comment: @bumba .... check the 4th edit..

Comment: I put `lp.x = 0;
  lp.y = 0;` But still some space on right and on bottom

Comment: @bumba comment out the lp.gravity line while trying to apply co ordinates manually

Comment: comented still the same

Comment: @bumba.. change the values of lp.x and lp.y... try to experiment... do changes to the code.. it will work...