# How to make activity not full screen?

Tags: android, android-activity

how to make the app not full screen, as in this screenshot?
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73143561/Screenshot_2013-05-29-05-47-07%5B1%5D.png

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910686/show-pop-up-like-gmail-in-android

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use this theme for your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

If you're using AppCompat, use

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
```

or

```
android:theme="@android:style/AppCompat.Light.Dialog"
```

Comment: if you're using AppCompt, use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" or AppCompat.Light.Dialog

Comment: I think @AndyWeinstein comments should be an answer. Was on the problem for hours