# android activity not full screen Theme.Dialog app has stopped

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, dialog

I made second activity with `ImageButton`. It was displayed fine with white space around. I want to make it not full screen. Here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911803/how-to-make-activity-not-full-screen) answers said add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.dialog"`. So now my `manifest`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

But now app crashs when Main2Activity is called by `startActivity`. Why?

Comment: why don't you add logcat?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have extended the AppCompatActivity class or some other class for Main2Activity class..try extending only the Activity class for Main2Activity

```
Public class Main2Activity extends Activity
```

Comment: But the Theme.Dialog works with Activity class because the AppCompatActivity needs you to use the AppCompat Theme

Comment: Yes. just now i identified. Sorry.

Comment: @Ameya Kulkarni, thank you. Maybe you also know how to get rid of app name label in dialog (I want only ImageButton)? I made custom style based on Theme.Dialog, what item should I add?

Comment: @Ameya Kulkarni, my question is answered below

Comment: You can also do that  by adding <item name ="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> in your custom style

Answer (score 1):

add this requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); before loading the setcontent

Answer (score 0):

You might have extended the AppCompatActivity class or some other class for Main2Activity class. If so, change 
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`
to 

 `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"`

Then it will work perfectly.