# How to set the layout and size of a PopupWindow

Tags: android, popupwindow

I'm writing my first program from android, and having difficulty getting a PopupWindow to be positioned and sized as I intend. As it currently is the popup will be activated after clicking a button on the menu bar. After clicking I was hoping to have the popup display centralised, however currently when clicked the result is the picture below (can't post image due to <10 reputation):

https://www.box.com/s/7d4qk8tqlvhiog7576mc

Java Popup Method and Listener:

```
public void showPopup(View add){
    PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.add);
    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    popup.showAtLocation(add, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
    popup.setFocusable(true);
    popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    View hideAdd = findViewById(R.id.add_task);
    hideAdd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
    switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.add_task:
            View addTaskView = findViewById(R.id.add_task);
            showPopup(addTaskView);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

}

Add Layout Xml:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/task_title"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/task_name"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="@string/task_prompt">

         </EditText>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure y you are taking this approach... but try to use the different types of dialogs available.. its much simpler..

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however I was under the impression that dialogs can only be used as an AlertDialog, or as Date/TimePickerDialog.
My intention for this popup is to provide an edittext field, and then pass the entered data into a stored list of tasks. Is that possible with a dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called a **custom dialog.**.. For example.:

1. You can design a layout and set it to a dialog..

   ```
    Dialog dialog=new Dialog();
    dialog.setContentView(the layout u designed here);
   ```
2. Convert an activity into dialog.. check my answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16910729/2219600)..

.. So there is endless possibilities with the dialogs..

Comment: Brilliant thank you, seems like a much simpler and useful solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change all "android:layout_width="match_parent"" in your xml to "android:layout_width="wrap_content""

Comment: Hi thanks to your reply, however it didn't seem to effect the result.

Comment: In my case I had a Switch using match_parent, once I changed it and the parent LinearLayout to wrap_content, it stopped sizing it wider than it needed to.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you set the visibility of the view underneeth to invisible. try commenting that and running again.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, however if you are referring to hideAdd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE), that function is to make the add button in the menu bar invisible, to prevent the user from constantly creating popups on top of each other